# How to set UIWindow bounds to support multitasking on iPad with iOS 9?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, ios9, multitasking

Apple has started support of multitasking for iPad. This is applicable after iOS9. With this enhancement in OS, key window will not have same size as `UIScreen` bounds. Also, it may change depends upon the second application which is running in parallel.

In this case, how to set bounds / frame / size of key window for iPad devices?

Comment: Why do you need to change the window size yourself? If you properly configure your app for multi-tasking, iOS will resize your window for you based on the user's input and your views will get notified about the size change so all you would need to do is to handle it. Are you asking how to configure your app for multi-tasking?

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 9 a simple call `[UIWindow new]` or `[[UIWindow alloc] init]` will set the right size automatically.

Comment: Where and how do I call this ?